# Multiple returns from a cell lookup

Tags: excel

I have text string in cells that I want to interrogate and then have all matching text values displayed in one cell.

I'm currently using:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("horse",G360)),
    "horse",
    IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cat",G360)),
       "cat",
       IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("monkey",G360)),
          "monkey", 
          IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("donkey",G346)),
          "donkey"))))
```

However of course this only shows the first matching value not ALL matching values. How would I do this?

If a cell contained text `"blah cat blah blah monkey blah blah horses"` the formula result would be `"Horse, Monkey"` not just `"Horse"`.

Comment: Are the cases you are testing for limited? Or above example is representative of your situation accurately?

Comment: a) What about *'blah blah **horse** blah **monkey** blah **horse** blah'* ? b) Are *horse* and *monkey* hard-coded or are they in a range list?

Comment: btw, if you type `=TEXTJOIN()` into a cell, do you get #VALUE! or #NAME! ?

Comment: Hi this is an example the true text is variable so cells could have as few as 30 characters through to many more but gives a representation of what I want the function to do.

Comment: That is, to scan text within a cell for defined values, within present formula it is hard coded, for example it could actually be to find horse and return equine as a formula result - but I want it to look up and return multiple values within a single cell for greater clarity

Answer (score 0):

In the sample even CAT will also come in I suppose.

For limited number of items case you could try:

`=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CONCATENATE(
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("horse",G360)),"horse "," "),
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("cat",G360)),"cat "," "),
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("monkey",G360)),"monkey "," "),
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("donkey",G346)),"donkey "," ")
))," ",", ")`